# showing QuickBooks data .qbw to self made php web-based application

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

I've been looking the answer for my own question but I still didn't find it, may I get the answer here.
I will try to explain my case. My office using Quick Books enterprise 2018 desktop version, I recently want to open new branch office, what I want is my branch office can always know the stock of inventory, so I want to convert `.qbw` to `MySql` and show it on web page so it can be accessed real time from branch office

First, is it possible to show `.qbw` database from Quick Books enterprise solution 2018 desktop application to web page which is using `php` and `MySql` database?
Second, how to do that? is there any specific SDK or API that I can use? Because I already read some of Quick Books Doc at their developer page but still no solution I found.

can you give me the link or pdf for tutorial
Thanks for the solution/suggestion

Comment: I would suggest a Google search for "QuickBooks PHP MySQL". You'll turn up quite a few relevant results which do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Certainly can be done, but it's one of the harder integrations out there given QB is proprietary software. My office is currently set up in such a manner with our Django app presenting QB data. If you're using QB hosting there is a API, but for desktop [check here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/01_quickbooks_desktop/1_get_started/00_get_started) there's also a tool you can use to test your connection [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/01_quickbooks_desktop/1_get_started/30_first_steps_with_the_sdktestplus3_tool). I know you can accomplish this with C# or Java with jacob-1.19.